# Looking for a way to list various image sequences in a directory

Tags: python

I have a directory with some image sequences that follow a similar naming convention, for example: test.1001.exr, test.1002.exr, test.1001.dpx, test.1002.dpx.

I'm trying to write some code that would output the following:

test.1001-1002.exr

test02.1001-1002.dpx

I found an example which does list them in the way I would like, however it is not very robust and would not show the file extension unless I print the specific one.

```
if os.path.exists(scanDir) is True:
    scans = []

    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(scanDir):
        for file in filenames:
            for ext in fileFormats:
                if ext in file:
                    scans.append(file)

    scans = [os.path.splitext(file)[0] for file in scans]
    scans.sort()

    def extract_number(name):
        return re.findall(r"\d+$", name)[0]

    def collapse_group(group):
        if len(group) == 1:
            return group[0][1]  # Unique names collapse to themselves.
        first = extract_number(group[0][1])  # Fetch range
        last = extract_number(group[-1][1])  # of this group.
        length = len(str(int(last)))
        return "%s%s-%s%s" % (group[0][1][:-length],
            first[-length:], last[-length:], ".dpx")

    groups = [collapse_group(tuple(group)) \
        for key, group in itertools.groupby(enumerate(scans),
            lambda index_name: index_name[0] - int(extract_number(index_name[1])))]
else:
    groups = []
```

I'm not sure I'm able to modify the code to achieve my result. Does anyone know a way I can do this?

Comment: How do you plan to do the grouping?  Do you want consecutive pairs of images?  How are the different extensions to be handled?  Note that `extract_number` for you can be as simple as `name.split('.')[1]`.  No regex necessary.

Comment: The grouping is what I was not sure about, because it should be flexible to handle any amount of image sequences of different file formats. The image sequences could start and end at any number. Thanks for the tip on extract_number!

Comment: It's unclear how you want the output to be because you have `test.1001-1002.exr` listed twice.

Comment: What I mean is, how many will you be combining?  Are you looking for a function that can group by any N?  Do the groups overlap?  (So, is it 1001-1004, then 1005-1008, or is it 1001-1004, 1002-1005, 1003-1006, etc?)

Comment: Sorry, thats terribly unclear. I mean to have a different file extension in the other. For example test.1001-1002.exr, and then test02.1001-1002.dpx.

Comment: It would be one large group to sort start/end frame of image sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct the following should work:

```
scans=['test.1001.exr', 'test.1002.exr', 'test.1003.exr', 'test.1001.dpx', 'test.1002.dpx',  'test.1003.dpx',  'test.1004.dpx',  'test.1005.dpx']
look_up={}
for scan in scans:
    file_extension=scan.split('.')[-1] # last element
    number=scan.split('.')[1]
    if file_extension not in look_up:
        look_up[file_extension]=[number]
    else:
        look_up[file_extension].append(number)

for file_extension in set(look_up.keys()):
    numbers=sorted(look_up[file_extension])
    Nmin=numbers[0]
    Nmax=numbers[-1]
    print("test.{0}-{1}.{2}".format(Nmin,Nmax, file_extension))
```

This gives you:

```
test.1001-1003.exr
test.1001-1005.dpx
```

**Important**: This code does not check if files between ´Nmin´ and ´Nmax´ are missing or duplicates